# Converting code from Python 2.6.5 to Python 3

Tags: python, network-programming, sys, python-sockets, python-os

So I got this book Violent Python and well knowing just a little bit of Python 3 figured I get this to learn more about Network Programming with Python. Now realizing that the book uses an older version of python I wanted to learn to learn to get the code to work on 3. So I did the basic stuff like changing the print statements and what not but can't seem to figure out what else is wrong with the code. any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket
import os
import sys


def retBanner(ip, port):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((ip, port))
        banner = s.recv(1024)
        return banner
    except Exception:
        return


def checkVulns(banner, filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.strip('\n') in banner:
            print(('[+] Server is vulnerable: ' +
                   banner.strip('\n')))


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        filename = sys.argv[1]
        if not os.path.isfile(filename):
            print(('[-] ' + filename +
                   ' does not exist.'))
            exit(0)

        if not os.access(filename, os.R_OK):
            print(('[-] ' + filename +
                   ' access denied.'))
            exit(0)
    else:
        print(('[-] Usage: ' + str(sys.argv[0]) +
               ' <vuln filename>'))
        exit(0)

    portList = [21, 22, 25, 80, 110, 443]
    for x in range(147, 150):
        ip = '192.168.95.' + str(x)
        for port in portList:
            banner = retBanner(ip, port)
            if banner:
                print(('[+] ' + ip + ' : ' + banner))
                checkVulns(banner, filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? What is happening instead?

Comment: The differences between Python 2 vs 3 aren't always trivial or cosmetic, indeed, the reason the two are considered different languages is because 3 is meant to have backwards compatibility-breaking changes. Suffice it to say, though, this isn't a code translation service. You should bring your question in a state of having been broken down just a little at least. Provide a [mcve]. At the very least, you should provide a description of your inputs and expected outputs, and an explanation in words of what your code is suppose to do. And all error messages, and things you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `2to3` script from python directory.
If don't have install it with `pip install 2to3` or `python -m pip install 2to3`.
Remember that you must run that script from command line like CMD on Windows and Bash on Unix [also called Linux] systems and specify script!
More info at [2to3 Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html).